# how to hide default keyboard when two or more keyboard in Android application

Tags: android, keyboard

In my application I implemented tamil, german keyboard and english has default keyboard, now I am selected tamil keyboard but I am receive the default keyboard after sending single message in english, I am getting keyboard for selected one.
now I need selected keyboard from first time itself. please help me

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this type of issue, on that time i find out the  way like in edit text i put OnTouchListener and my code is

`EditText text = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tamil);

text.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

```
            @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                tamilkeyboard();
                return false;
            }
```

private void tamilkeyboard() {

// call your keyboard code here

```
         }

    });`
```

Hope this will help you